# Python: how to remove key from list and keep value?

Tags: python

I have an array like this

```
myarr = [
[{'text':'da','id':'aa','info':'aaa'},{'text':'da','id':'aa','info':'aaa'},{'text':'da','id':'aa','info':'aaa'}],
[{'text':'da','id':'aa','info':'aaa'},{'text':'da','id':'aa','info':'aaa'},{'text':'da','id':'aa','info':'aaa'}]
]
```

I need result:

```
myarr = [
[['da','aa','aaa'],['da','aa','aaa'],['da','aa','aaa']],
[['da','aa','aaa'],['da','aa','aaa'],['da','aa','aaa']]
]
```

How can i get sample result? Please help me!

Comment: Do you want the dictionary brackets too in the output?

Comment: You output is not a valid python data structure. Also please show what have you tried so far

Comment: I want to remove key text, id, info including {} and :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a list comprehension -

```
# l will iterate over each inner list and
# e will iterate over dictionaries in each inner list
myarr = [[list(e.values()) for e in l] for l in myarr]
print(myarr)
```

Ouput:

```
[[['da', 'aa', 'aaa'], ['da', 'aa', 'aaa'], ['da', 'aa', 'aaa']], [['da', 'aa', 'aaa'], ['da', 'aa', 'aaa'], ['da', 'aa', 'aaa']]]
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you refresh the page to see the results again?

Comment: @Trong, yes. changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

For some variety, you could also use:

```
myarr = [[*map(list, map(dict.values, x))] for x in myarr]
```

Comment: descriptor 'values' for 'dict' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object, looks like it doesn't apply to list

Comment: You're probably trying to run it on the already modified `myarr`.  This works with your given input.

Comment: ohh. My bad! Exactly `myarr ` changed.